# How to control the open connections to some IP's for a running program by using c#

Tags: c#, utorrent

I need to monitor and control a
program running on my
machine(utorrent).  This program
establish connections to other PCs on
the internet.  I can know the IPs
which he is connecting to from a list
on it I need to control these
connections,limit them or close them
and control the bandwidth they are
using.

How can i get all the connected
IP's to utorrent and control them all
by certain conditions i can put later
using C# 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful it is, but try looking at WinPcap develpment tools:
http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm
It's a c library, not C#, but maybe it'll help you.